# Excel true empty cell problem which doesn't break a string in a previous left side cell

Tags: excel, cell

I found some resources about blank cells in Excel and cell formatting but it's not my case.
Also I found the nice video about zero, blank and empty issues in the Excel () FIY.

Excel Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148)
I have a problem with simplest case of 2 cells.
Left cell A and right cell B.
Cell A has a long text string.
Cell be has a formula.
A formula in B returns NA() or "".
In both cases the text of cell A is shorted or broken :)

a) cell B has no formula and no spaces and no ""

```
|   A1      |   B1      |
|-----------|-----------|
|ajshdgashdg|asdhaskjdkd|
```

b) cell B has a formula which returns na() or "", for instance an IF formula.

```
|   A1      |   B1      |
|-----------|-----------|
|ajshdgashdg|           |
```

The string in cell A is broken or shorted.

The question is - any solution to do not brake a text in cell A if the formula in cell B should return TRUE empty?
PS: formatting in my experience doesn't solve the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is formula do you use to column B? You can't see `""` in cell because it is empty string. You can check it by `ISBLANK()` function.

Comment: Make column A wide enough to show the whole value, or Wrap the text.  If column B contains anything - even a space, then it will hide what's overflowing from column A.